# query dict python http request

Tags: python, http

question: Write a function named "query_dict" that a key-value store as a parameter mapping strings to floating point numbers. The function will make an HTTPS GET request to the url "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a" with a query string containing the same key-value pairs from the input key-value store. The response from the server will be a JSON string representing an object in the format "{"answer": }" where  is a floating point Number. Return the value at the key "answer" as a float

```
import urllib.request
import json
psp = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a"
def query_dict(strfloat):
    query = "?"
    for i in strfloat:
        query += (str(i) + "=" + str(strfloat[i]) + "&")
        query = query [:1]
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(psp + query)
        content_string = response.read().decode()
        content = json.loads(content_string)
        return float(content["answer"])
```

function query_dict incorrect on input [{'z': 4, 'y': 0, 'x': 5}]

returned: -1.0
expected: 176.7

how do i fix that?

Comment: I'd recommend using the `requests` library, it provides a much nicer interface.  you can do `requests.get(psp, params=strfloat)`

Comment: I want to, but my professor has disabled that library on these practice problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query += (i + "=" + str(strfloat[i]) + "&")`

Modify the above line to:

`query += (str(i) + "=" + str(strfloat[i]) + "&")`  **Notice the str() and the bracket after `strfloat[i]`**

Python cannot add an integer with a string directly. You have to typecast the integer to string for string concatenation. You were also not type-casting the value of `strfloat[i]` properly, due to incorrect placement of the brackets.

**EDIT:** Updated code should look like this:

```
def query_dict(strfloat):
    query = "?"

    for i in strfloat:
        query += (str(i) + "=" + str(strfloat[i]) + "&")

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(psp + query)
    content_string = response.read().decode()
    content = json.loads(content_string)
    return float(content["answer"])
```

Comment: What's the error traceback? Edit it on the question, itself.

Comment: Just that? Okay, then. What is strfloat, as well?

Comment: It's the name of my input parameter

Comment: What is it exactly? Is it a string, a list containing string objects? Send a complete example of the input parameter

Comment: that a key-value store as a parameter mapping strings to floating point numbers.

Comment: Is it a dictionary? If yes, are you storing your dictionary in a list?

Comment: Yeah, it is a dictionary. Not sure what you mean by the second part, I'm very new to python.

Comment: I have updated the answer. By the second part I meant, that you are using the dictionary as `dict = {..}` and not as `dict = [{ .. }]`. The latter is incorrect.

Comment: query += (str(i) + "=" + str(strfloat[i]) + "&"))  it's giving a syntax error but i don't see what's wrong with it, it isn't even telling me what the syntax error is, on a side note thanks for all the help you're giving, sorry i may be asking stupid questions, i'm new to python programming.

Comment: There's an extra bracket after `"&"`, in your query. And in the answer as well. :P

Comment: ah i see, i fixed it and the unorderable type is gone, this is the output it gave now,                                                                                                       
function query_dict incorrect on input [{'z': 4, 'y': 0, 'x': 5}]

returned: -1.0
expected: 176.7

Comment: That's because your `request` method is in the `for` loop. I tried with a few modifications to get 176.7. I have updated the answer, have a look at it.